# How to deal with wrong password in my login script in shell?

Tags: linux, shell, while-loop, samba

I made a backup script that uploads files to a file-sharing windows server, using the `smbclient` command. My script works correctly but if the user types an incorrect username or password, the script stops. I would like it to ask for the login and password again until it is correct.

I tried to do this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

unset user
unset pass
testLoginValue=false

while [[ "$testLoginValue" = false ]]; do
        while [ -z ${user} ]; do
                read -p "Username: " user
        done
        while [ -z ${pass} ]; do
                read -sp "Password: " pass
        done

        testLogin=$(smbclient '\\my.windows.server.ip\folder\' $pass -U domain\\$user -c 'help') # This connect to the server and get the result of the "help" command

        if [[ $testLogin == "session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE" ]]; then
                echo "Username or password incorrect."
        else
                echo "Successful connection."
                testLoginValue=true
        fi
done

echo "the script will continue..."
```

The problem is that with this code, the script echo `"Username or password incorrect."` in loop without stoping. I would like it to echo `"Username or password incorrect."` just one time an ask for the credentials again. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The vars `user` and `pass` must be `unset` again. Start with

```
#!/bin/bash
testLoginValue="false"

while [[ "${testLoginValue}" = "false" ]]; do
   unset user
   unset pass
   while [ -z "${user}" ]; do
      read -p "Username: " user
   done
   while [ -z "${pass}" ]; do
     read -sp "Password: " pass
   done
```

Off-topic: Perhaps change the loop into

```
while :; do
   ...
   if [[ "${somevar}" = "Successful connection." ]]; then
      break
   fi
done
```